# Positioning a div relative to scroll position

Tags: javascript, html, css

This script shows and positions a div
like:

```
function myfunction()  
{  
   obj.style.visibility = "visible";
   obj.style.width: "100%";  
   obj.style.height = "100%";  
   obj.style.position = "absolute";
   obj.style.top: "0px";
   obj.style.left: "0px";
   obj.style.z-index = "44";  
   obj.focus()  
 }
```

and so on 
`<b onclick="myfunction()">Click here</b>`

Of course it's a bit more than that, but this is to show you what I'm trying to do.
This works well, the div fills the screen like it should.

The problem is when sometimes we display a lot of links so the user has to scroll.. when the div shows its always on the top of the page and the user gets scrolled up there when it gets focus. When the user is done and closes the div, he has to find his way back down the list where he was.

Is there any way to position the div relative to the browsers scroll position?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

as long as you have the

```
position: fixed;
```

will be be ok...

or am I missing something here?

---

Take a look at, for example, UserVoice announce image in several sites, like tr.im (now defunct)

it has the behaviour that, I think, you are trying to accomplish, am I right?

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-23_1449.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-23_1449.png)

the css that you can grab from FireBug is:

```
a#uservoice-feedback-tab {
   background:#A5C1D1 url(http://feedback.tr.im/images/feedback_tab_black.png) no-repeat scroll -2px 50%;
   border-color:#A5C1D1 -moz-use-text-color #A5C1D1 #A5C1D1;
   border-style:outset none outset outset;
   border-width:1px medium 1px 1px;
   display:block;
   height:90px;
   margin-top:-45px;
   position:fixed;
   right:0;
   top:40%;
   width:25px;
   z-index:100001;
}
```

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-23_1450.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-09-23_1450.png)

try to apply to your code :)

Comment: That totally did it. Can't believe it was that simple :)
Thanks

Comment: added one way to, instead of waiting for an answer ... put your hand dirty and D-I-Y :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use an expression in CSS, something like that:

```
.div {
position:fixed;
top:expression(window.scrollTop + "px");
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

could use position:fixed, but you'd lose IE6 unless you use one of the hacks to get around the IE6 incompatibility.

Comment: IE6 compatibility is not an issue. This webpage will only be shown on a intranet where no clients run IE 6

Answer (score 0):

I used this to do it:  http://www.pixelbind.com/make-a-div-stick-when-you-scroll/#comment-800

But I had to edit the CSS to use "absolute", not "fixed" - which gets around the IE bug and allows you to be able to specify the number in pixels from the top where you want to display the div.

Try:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
var s = $("#sticker");
var pos = s.position();                    
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    s.css("top", windowpos + 150);
    //s.html("Distance from top:" + pos.top + "<br />Scroll position: " + windowpos);
    s.html("<table width='750' align='center' style='color:white;font-face:Times;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline'><tr><td align='center' width='61%'>Column 1</td><td align='center'><span style='' width='10%'>Column 2</td><td align='center' width='29%'>Column 3</td></tr></table>");
    if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
        s.addClass("stick");
        $(".linebreak").show();
    } else {
        s.removeClass("stick"); 
        $(".linebreak").hide();
    }
});
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">

div#sticker {
padding:11px;
background:#AAA;
}
.stick {
position:absolute;
z-index:-10;
color:white;
}
</style>
```

and adding rows to a table to get a table row that follows the table as you scroll:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
    <div id="sticker" class="stick">
        <table width="780" style="text-decoration:underline;color:white;font-weight:bold">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" width="61%">Column 1</td>
                <td align="center" width="10%">Column 2</td>
                <td align="center" width="29%">Column 3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="linebreak"><p>&nbsp;</p></td></tr>
<tr><td class="linebreak"><p>&nbsp;</p></td></tr>
<tr><td class="linebreak"><p>&nbsp;</p></td></tr>
```